# TabFolder with single item on OS X

Tags: java, macos, swt

I created a **tab folder with one tabitem**. When i execute this ui on *mac* it does not show me the title of tab item properly.   If i create two or more tab item then its all titles are visible.  I executed this code on *windows there is not any problem* with it.

I tried to search on google for the same but not have satisfied answer or solution.
If any body can solve this by giving proper justification.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot and a minimal working example of your code?

Answer (score 0):

Don't create a single-item tab folder or, if it really should look like a tab, try `CTabFolder`.

Comment: Code is return such a way it creates tab folders runtime based on conditions. but i will try with CTabFolder.